# Capture Command line response in an Electron/NodeJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I need to execute command line commands from an ElectronJS App which also has NodeJS available and then capture the response from those commands ran.

The Xampp Windows WAMP Dev Server app shown below has an example of capturing the command response and showing it in an app.

How can I do this in a NodeJS/ElectronJS app?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module `Child Proccess` using the method `exec`. The documantation for it is pretty clear and can be seen in this link: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

The command line response will be in the stdout parameter of the callback function.